# How to "connect" my facebook page to my wbsite/domain?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

I created a Facebook page a year ago, and last month I created a website (Wordpress) that I want to have that Facebook page connected to. I've tried to set my personal facebook account (which is admin of the Facebook page in question) as fb:admins in a meta tag on my website, but Facebook still says my website/domain has 0 likes. My Facebook page has a few thousand likes.

In short: I want the my Facebook page (and it's likes) to be connected to my domain. So when someone likes my website/domain, it adds to the likes of my facebook page. How do I accomplish this?

My meta tags look like this (I've changed the domain to "example.com" and my facebook page to "myfacebookpage" and my personal facebook ID is replaced with 0:s, but if it is necessary I can provide the actual website and id):

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.7.4 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="sv_SE" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Website Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description of website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Website Title" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="0000000000" />
<script type="application/ld+json">{ "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebSite", "url": "http://example.com", "potentialAction": { "@type": "SearchAction", "target": "example.com/?s={search_term}", "query-input": "required name=search_term" } }</script>
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

Any help more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't work the way you think. Connecting your website with your Facebook fanpage doesn't mean all the likes will be passed one to another.

The `fb:admins` meta tag just allows you to getting access to the data available via Facebook Insights.

In case of a need of having the Facebook like button associated with the fan page just change its URL to the URL of the fan page.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. So the only way to have a Facebook page connected to a website is to create the website first and the Facebook page after?

Comment: Not really. Can you explain a bit more what you mean with connecting a fb page to a website?

Comment: Specifically I want to use this box: http://conversionsbox.com/. It shows a like button for my website/domain, but according to Facebook my website has zero likes. But my facebook page for my website is what I would like to be the "official" page of my domain. I have other websites where this works, but for them I created the website first and the Facebook page after, so when those Facebook pages were created i guess I told Facebook from the start that "This is the official Facebook page for example.com".

Comment: And what about setting the URL of the ConversionBox to your Facebook URL (http://facebook.com/YOURFANPAGE) ? You will get the number of its likes, and it's not a problem to place the code on your website even when URL is different. Will it work for you?

Comment: That worked! Gosh, so simple. Thanks a lot, really appreciate it!